# How to use Spatie Role and Permission For Admin?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

**This is the Migration file which is created By Spatie and I want to use spatie for the admin panel and every tutorial having the usage for the User model and I have both user and admin model. I did not understand how to connect this with my admin model or admin db table because by default it is taking the user model and user table **

```
 class CreatePermissionTables extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    $tableNames = config('permission.table_names');
    $columnNames = config('permission.column_names');

    if (empty($tableNames)) {
        throw new \Exception('Error: config/permission.php not loaded. Run [php artisan config:clear] and try again.');
    }

    Schema::create($tableNames['permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('guard_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('guard_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create($tableNames['model_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames, $columnNames) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');

        $table->string('model_type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['model_morph_key']);
        $table->index([$columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'], 'model_has_permissions_model_id_model_type_index');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                'model_has_permissions_permission_model_type_primary');
    });

    Schema::create($tableNames['model_has_roles'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames, $columnNames) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

        $table->string('model_type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['model_morph_key']);
        $table->index([$columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'], 'model_has_roles_model_id_model_type_index');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on($tableNames['roles'])
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id', $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                'model_has_roles_role_model_type_primary');
    });

    Schema::create($tableNames['role_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on($tableNames['roles'])
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id'], 'role_has_permissions_permission_id_role_id_primary');
    });

    app('cache')
        ->store(config('permission.cache.store') != 'default' ? config('permission.cache.store') : null)
        ->forget(config('permission.cache.key'));
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    $tableNames = config('permission.table_names');

    if (empty($tableNames)) {
        throw new \Exception('Error: config/permission.php not found and defaults could not be merged. Please publish the package configuration before proceeding, or drop the tables manually.');
    }

    Schema::drop($tableNames['role_has_permissions']);
    Schema::drop($tableNames['model_has_roles']);
    Schema::drop($tableNames['model_has_permissions']);
    Schema::drop($tableNames['roles']);
    Schema::drop($tableNames['permissions']);
}
```

}

Comment: are admins going to have different permissions and roles?

Comment: yes, i'm defining different role and permission for admins, their will be multiple admins.